# React.cloneElement { ReactComponent as SomeSVG }

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get an SVG, which is passed as a prop. After I get it in the child component I want to add some props like that:

```
{React.cloneElement(ReactSVGasProp, { className: class })}
```

But I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace `ReactSVGasProp` with `<ReactSVGasProp/>`